# Can I extend Tuples in Swift?

Tags: swift, tuples, swift-extensions, swift-protocols

I'd like to write an extension for tuples of (e.g.) two value in Swift. For instance, I'd like to write this `swap` method:

```
let t = (1, "one")
let s = t.swap
```

such that `s` would be of type `(String, Int)` with value `("one", 1)`. (I know I can very easily implement a `swap(t)` function instead, but that's not what I'm interested in.)

Can I do this? I cannot seem to write the proper type name in the `extension` declaration.

Additionally, and I suppose the answer is the same, can I make a 2-tuple adopt a given protocol?

Comment: The [Swift documentation for Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html) distuingishes between *named types* and *compound types*.  Named types can be extended, but tuples (and functions) are compound types.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. Looks like this is a definite “no”, then. Can you turn it into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: The most customisation you can do with Tuples is naming the parameters and using a `typealias` for it. For anything more complex you should use `struct`s or define global functions (maybe with generics)

Comment: man... it would be mindblowing to be able to define extensions on typealiases... I am ready to accept enforcing of some kind like (use the same naming as declared in the tuple or whatever)...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You cannot extend tuple types in Swift.
According to
[Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html), there are *named types* (which
can be extended) and *compound types*. Tuples and functions are compound
types.

See also (emphasis added):

> [**Extensions**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html)
>   Extensions add new functionality to an existing
>   **class, structure, or enumeration type**.

Answer (score 6):

As the answer above states, you cannot extend tuples in Swift. However, rather than just give you a no, what you can do is box the tuple inside a `class`, `struct` or `enum` and extend that.

```
struct TupleStruct {
    var value: (Int, Int)
}
extension TupleStruct : Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return hash()
    }
    func hash() -> Int {
        var hash = 23
        hash = hash &* 31 &+ value.0
        return hash &* 31 &+ value.1
    }
}

func ==(lhs: TupleStruct, rhs: TupleStruct) -> Bool {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value
}
```

As a side note, in Swift 2.2, tuples with up to 6 members are now `Equatable`.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to be a Bad Person™ you can define custom operators on tuples, like this:

```swift
postfix operator <->

postfix func <-> <A, B>(lhs: (A, B)) -> (B, A) {
    return (lhs.1, lhs.0)
}

let initial = (1, "one")
let reversed = initial<->
```

FWIW I can't think of a place where my 'clever' code trumps the readability of just writing your `swap` function.

Comment: That is awful :D I need to add that to my ”horrible operator hacks in Swift” document.

Answer (score 0):

### Details

- Xcode 11.2.1 (11B500), Swift 5.1

### Solution

```
struct Tuple<T> {
    let original: T
    private let array: [Mirror.Child]
    init(_ value: T) {
        self.original = value
        array = Array(Mirror(reflecting: original).children)
    }

    func getAllValues() -> [Any] { array.compactMap { $0.value } }
    func swap() -> (Any?, Any?)? {
        if array.count == 2 { return (array[1].value, array[0].value) }
        return nil
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
let x = (1, "one")
let tuple = Tuple(x)
print(x)                                        // (1, "one")
print(tuple.swap())                             // Optional((Optional("one"), Optional(1)))
if let value = tuple.swap() as? (String, Int) {
    print("\(value) | \(type(of: value))")      // ("one", 1) | (String, Int)
}
```